# How to put install path into installed pod documentation?

Tags: perl, perl-pod, dist-zilla

Is there a way to have the pod documentation for an installed Perl module include information which depends on the actual install path used?

I have a module which ships with a directory containing example scripts.  In the build tree this directory is share/examples/ and Dist::Zilla somehow arranges for it to be installed at .../site_perl/5.34.0/auto/share/dist/Package-Name/examples/ .   That is so obscure as to be useless the documentation can point the user to it.

I'm guessing maybe Pod::Weaver run (somehow) from Makefile.PL during installation, receiving the install path as a parameter from the Makefile... but how?